# How to remove downscrollbar in pdf

Tags: html, typescript

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documents',
  templateUrl: './documents.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./documents.component.less']
})
export class DocumentsComponent implements OnInit {

  pdfSrc: string = '';
  pdfZoom:number = 1;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pdfSrc = '/assets/demo.pdf';
  }
  public zoomIn()
 {
  this.pdfZoom += 0.25;
 }

 public zoomOut()
 {
      if (this.pdfZoom > 1) {
   this.pdfZoom -= 0.25;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="m-portlet m-portlet--mobile">
  
    <div class=modal-body align="center">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn" name="zoomout" (click)="zoomOut()"><i class="fa fa-search-minus"> </i></button>
        <button class="btn" name="zoomin" (click)="zoomIn()"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"> </i></button>
      </span>
    </div><br>
    
  <div class="m-portlet__body" style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y: scroll;max-height:75vh;">
    <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" [original-size]="false" [zoom]="pdfZoom" [page]="page"
          [show-all]="true" [autoresize]="true" style="display: block;">
        </pdf-viewer>
      
  </div>



</div>


<!--<img src="assets/common/images/sampleProfilePics/a.jpg" height="432" width="405" />-->
```

I created a layout. On that I'm using ng2-pdfviewer package to add pdf documents on layout page,and with that created zoomin and zoom out button,and overflow-x and overflow-y scrollbars.but overflow-y scrollbar only working but overflow-x is not working why because horizontal scroll bar is coming with pdf itself.
So,I want to remove that predifined horizontal scroll bar.